# How to share versioned data within a pod

Tags: kubernetes, data-containers

We are currently serving around 140 webapps created by a bunch of different web agencies. The setup is the usual LEMP stack.

A 1.2 k8s cluster has been installed to migrate them as micro-services.
The problem we are facing is about serving static and dynamic content. 
For this purpose we use, of course, two different containers (nginx and php-fpm) but we can't find an adequate solution to share data on both of them.

We hoped to be able to use versioned data containers but it is apparently not in the scope of k8s. Too bad.

gitRepo is not an option as we don't want to be dependent of a working git infra to instance pods. If it doesn't work we want to be autonomous and be able to serve traffic.

The other options (flocker, etc.) look heavy and complex in comparison to a simple data container. We also would like to be independent of data storage.

Is there an option I am not aware of? Does anyone have an advise on this?
Let me emphasise that we want to be able to version things in order to roll forward / backward easily.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but `git` doesn't require an "infrastructure".  It operates entirely locally.  While it has the ability to sync changes to/from a remote location, that's not necessary for basic version tracking.

Comment: IMHO git in container is not good concept. Why you don't build docker image and then use git commit id used in the image as Docker image tag? It's more k8s friendly solution.

Comment: @janGaraj that's a good idea but if I get it correctly, that'd mean we'd have to have the code in two containers in the same pod, once in nginx and once in php-fpm, is that what you mean? Is there really no way to share data between containers in a common pod?

Comment: @dynek In docker world it's easy --volume-from. In Kubernetes world it's more complicated - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538210/how-to-mimic-volumes-from-in-kubernetes

Comment: I have seen this before posting my question. I thought it might have changed since 1 year. Copying files from a data container onto an EmptyDir does look like a solution. It, however, looks heavy. Well it's normally done once per pod and usually websites shouldn't be too big.